# Replace the string of certain complex pattern with empty string

Tags: python, regex

I parsed some texts from web with multiple useless strings with certain pattern as demonstrated below.

```
Some Text1adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_9")});Some Text2adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_10")});Some Text3adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_11")});Some Text4
```

I would like to replace the string with the substring `"function(ads {ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_%d")});"` to empty space. How can I do that with str.replace or regular expression? The expected output should be something like:

```
Some Text1  Some Text2  Some Text3  Some Text4
```

I have tried `str.replace("function(ads {ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_%d")});", " ")` but it won't work.

Comment: `%d` is not a regular expression. `\d` is the regular expression that matches a number.

Comment: You need to put the regexp in `//`. And you need to escape all the characters that have special meaning in regular expressions, like `(` and `)`. I think you need to start by reading a regexp tutorial.  Go to www.regular-expression.info.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read carefully and started to solve it a bit different (I guess in that case a bit long-winded) but maybe it helps anyway.

```
text = 'Some Text1adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_9")});Some Text2adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_10")});Some Text3adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_11")});Some Text4'
pattern = re.compile(r"([\w\s]+(?:\d))")

text_list = text.split(';')
result = []
for elem in text_list:
    m = re.match(pattern,elem)
    result.append(m.group(1))

output = '; '.join(result) # or ''.join(result) for no delim
print(output)
'Some Text1; Some Text2; Some Text3; Some Text4'
```

And for your attempt with replace. I chose `re.sub` to solve it.

```
output = re.sub(r"(?<=Text\d)(.*?)(?=;)", " ", text)
print(output)
'Some Text1 ;Some Text2 ;Some Text3 ;Some Text4'
```

In case you don't want delimiter:

```
output2 = re.sub(r"(?<=Text\d)(.*?;)(?=Some)", " ", text)
print(output2)
'Some Text1 Some Text2 Some Text3 Some Text4'
```

**UPDATE:**
For the extra question from the comments:
We need to split by whitespace but make sure that it doesn't split at every whitespace. This one will only split if there is a number followed by a whitespace followed by a number with a dot.

```
text = 'dummytext1 1. dummytext2 2. dummytext3 3. dummytext4'
output3 = re.split(r"(?<=\d)\s(?=\d\.)", text)
print(output3)
['dummytext1', '1. dummytext2', '2. dummytext3', '3. dummytext4']
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am trying to find some insights behind it. Additionally, do you know how I should split text by the pattern of a number with a period? I tried re.split(r'^(\d+)\.\s', text) but it splits nothing. Do you know where could be wrong?

Comment: "number with a period" ? I don't think I understand. Can you make an example what should be splitted ? Are we talking about the same string from your question ? or something else now

Comment: For instance, input text string is 'dummytext1 1. dummytext2 2. dummytext3 3. dummytext4' and I tried to split it into a text by the number followed by the period. The expected output is something like ['dummytext1', '1. dummytext2' '2. dummytext3' '3. dummytext4']. Is regular expression be able to do that?

Comment: hm good question. I'm also quite new with getting the logic of regex, but from what I understand the pattern you provide won't appear in your result list. In this example you don't cut off anything.I'm not sure how this can be done at the moment, but I will try for a bit

Comment: got it ! I will update my answer

Comment: @TommyYu if you are content with my answer, please consider voting/accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could match for example a piece of the text specific enough to get the right match, and for the replacement, you can use 2 capture groups.

```
({ads\.prime\("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_)\d+("\)})
```

**Explanation**

- `({ads\.prime\("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_)` Capture *group 1*,  match the part before the digits, and escape the dot and opening parenthesis:
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits (which are to be replaced)
- `("\)})` Capture *group 2*, match `")}`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NrqQNs/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oja8gq).

**Example code**

```
import re

regex = r'({ads\.prime\("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_)\d+("\)})'

s = 'Some Text1adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_9")});Some Text2adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_10")});Some Text3adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_11")});Some Text4'

print(re.sub(regex, r"\1%d\2", s))
```

**Output**

```
Some Text1adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_%d")});Some Text2adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_%d")});Some Text3adCommands.push(function(ads){ads.prime("mid_leaderboard_rectangle_%d")});Some Text4
```